# How to allow multiple values to be entered in a search filter (a textbox). and what will be the impact on performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance

There is a new enhancement in my project, i need to add a new textbox filter in which i have to allow multiple values to be entered.

obviously i am using "like" for a single valued parameter in my current procedure.

```
WHERE (@_adFirstName IS NULL OR firstName LIKE @_adFirstName + '%')
        AND (@_adLastName IS NULL OR lastName LIKE @_adLastName + '%')
```

later i need to use "IN" for multiple values. what will be the impact of performane of procedure in this scenario.

Comment: should be minimal, you code will be cleaner if you just run the same search x times though

Comment: Thanks Soner for edit :)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't specify your sql server version, but since 2008 sql server supports table valued parameters. I find this to be the most effective way of passing a list of variables to a stored procedure.

You can find a complete description on how it's done in [my answer to another question here.]
([How to pass string array in SQL parameter to IN clause in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24879020/how-to-pass-string-array-in-sql-parameter-to-in-clause-in-sql/24881759#24881759))

Comment: [Here is tge link to msdn about this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). Sorry for not including it in my answer, i wrote it on my cellphone and paste is making a mess.