# Split colon separated key value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am passing a keyword to my SP say @Keyword. This keyword may include

```
param1:value1 param2:value2

param1:value1 

param2:value2
```

How can I can grab value1 and value2?

Comment: Give Some Example Datas , so it will easy to give u the Exact answer

Comment: Have you used search in sites like `name:abc value:good`

Comment: So u need to grab 'abc' and 'Good' separately  right? Give me Example value u passing in @keyword.

Comment: Can I be the bad guy here, and ask why you want to do it this way? Use a table valued parameter.

Comment: @Bridge, I just need to use this function everywhere

Comment: Don't pass composite arguments to a stored procedure like that. use a table value parameter. [read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24881759/3094533)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

You can use `.nodes` for xml type and string functions like `LEFT / CHARINDEX / SUBSTRING` to achieve this

**Query**

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(MAX) = 'param1:value1 param2:value2'

DECLARE @xml xml = '<x>' + REPLACE(@v,' ','</x><x>') + '</x>'
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT c.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') as val
FROM @xml.nodes('x') t(c)
)
SELECT
LEFT(val,CHARINDEX(':',val)-1),
SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX(':',val)+1,LEN(val)-CHARINDEX(':',val))
FROM cte
```

If possible, you should use static parameters. if not I would suggest you can use Table valued parameters or xml directly as a parameter.

***Note:** The above code assumes that `<x>`,`</x>` and `' '` space are not valid param or value.*

Here is another way,

```
            ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetValueByKey]
            (
                @Key nvarchar(max)
                ,@Str nvarchar(max)
            )
            RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            AS
            BEGIN

                DECLARE @Result nvarchar(max) = '';
                DECLARE @KeyIndex int = 0; 
                DECLARE @SpaceIndex int = 0; 

                SELECT @KeyIndex = CHARINDEX(@Key + ':', @Str);

                IF(@KeyIndex > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @KeyIndex = @KeyIndex + LEN(@Key) + 1;
                    SET @Result = SUBSTRING(@Str, @KeyIndex, LEN(@Str) - @KeyIndex + 1);
                    SELECT @SpaceIndex = CHARINDEX(' ', @Result);
                    IF(@SpaceIndex <= 1)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @SpaceIndex = LEN(@Result)  +1;
                    END
                    SELECT @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result, 0, @SpaceIndex)
                END

                RETURN @Result;
            END
```

Comment: But it can be anything :(

Comment: well if space is also allowed as a value, how will splitting `param1:value1 param2:value2` work?

Comment: Updated your answer because I have also found a way.

Comment: Since your answer is fundamentally different than mine, I would suggest you to create a new answer or even better add it in your question as an edit and mention that this is what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

How about just putting param1 and param2 as parameters to your stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedurename
    @param1   datatype
  , @param2   datatype
AS
  content here
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using a split function. See this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) by Jeff Moden for reference.

Basically, you want to split your `@keyword` using `' '` (space) as the delimiter. Then using some string functions such as `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`, and `CHARINDEX`, you can extract the `param` and its `value`.

```
DECLARE @keyword VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @keyword = 'param1:value1 param2:value2'

;WITH CteSpace AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@keyword, ' ')
)
SELECT
    Param = LEFT(Item, CHARINDEX(':', Item) - 1),
    Value = SUBSTRING(Item, CHARINDEX(':', Item) +1, LEN(Item) - CHARINDEX(':', Item))
FROM CteSpace
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a delimited string, use a [tabled value parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead.
Create a [user defined table type](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) that contains 2 columns: paramName and value:

```
CREATE TYPE Keywords AS Table
(
    Keyword_ParamName varchar(10), -- or whatever length that suits your needs
    Keyword_value varchar(200), -- or whatever length that suits your needs
)
```

Then simply declare the `@keyword` parameter as this type:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stp_doWhatever 
(
    @Keyword dbo.Keywords READONLY -- Note: Readonly is a must!
)
AS
-- do whatever
```

You can use the `@keyword` as a table in the stored procedure to perform selects, joins, whatever you need.