# dynamic filters and sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which has a parameter @SomeFilterIds, which takes in comma separated integer ids. If this parameter is not NULL it is translated into something like this:

```
AND [X] IN(1, 2, 4)
```

and assigned to @SomeFilter

I then used something along those lines:

```
SET @Sql = N' ...WHERE    
 c.SomeDate >= @SomeDate
' + @SomeFilter
```

and:

```
SET @ParameterDefinition = N'@SomeDate DateTime';
EXEC sp_executesql 
@Sql
,@ParameterDefinition
,@SomeDate = @SomeDate
```

I would think that this is not best practice and opens potential security holes. Is this correct? Can this be improved? Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a dynamic sql? if passing a comma delimited string of values is the only reason for this, then there are better ways such as using a table valued parameter.

Comment: I need it for other reasons too.

Comment: Ok, but do you **really** need it? dynamic sql should be the last resort, as it's both dangerous and slow. perhaps someone might be able to show you a way to avoid it if you can share the relevant details.

Comment: Zohar please be so kind and provide an alternative (answer). Strong requirement sproc receives @SomeDate (DataTime) and comma separated list of integer Ids (see example).

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24881759/3094533) to see how to pass a table valued parameter to a stored procedure from c#, but I can't give you an exact answer without knowing what you actually need to do and what code is executing the stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of  `@SomeFilterIds` as varchar parameter you can use `XML` type variable and then  use Inner join your main table with this XML variable.
This will avoid dynamic query execution and will be be safer.

Example:

```
--Instead of comma separated ID use below XML
declare @xml xml = '<row><ID>1</ID></row><row><ID>3</ID></row>'

--Assume this is your other table
declare @YourTable table (ItemId int, ColA varchar(20))

insert @YourTable
select 1, 'Hello World'


--Joining both the tables

select  col.value('data(ID[1])', 'int') as ID
from    @xml.nodes('/row') tbl(col) 
inner join @YourTable t2 
on t2. ItemId=tbl.col.value('data(ID[1])', 'int')
--WHERE  c.SomeDate >= @SomeDate
```

Comment: Can u please provide example?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I really do not understand what this has to do with my question and sp_executesql. Please also not that I do the filtering in where.

Comment: Basically I am suggesting you to avoid dynamic query.I am assuming you are using sp_executesql because of list of comma separated Ids.So by  using IDs in XML you can avoid dynamic query.
And if you see my example I have mentioned where condition also but it is commented.That is the place where you can write your other conditions.